# Problem with NMOS not turning fully on and off

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, error

I have a circuit that consists of a relay, two NMOS transistors and some pin headers used for connecting a load.

[image]

[image]

The differential input voltage is connected to J20. The relay acts as a switch controlled by Q6 driven by an onboard Arduino Micro. When the relay is closed and a load is connected between J21 and J22 current can flow in a closed loop.

\$V_\text{SUPPLY}\$ is a 5 V voltage supplied from a lab bench power supply. \$V_\text{SUPPLY}\$ and the Arduino Micro have common GND.

R28, R29 and R30 are unused.

Q12 (also controlled by the Arduino) acts as an additional switch that makes pin 1 and 2 of J22 able to carry current as well. This is the transistor I have trouble with. It never seems to turn fully off or fully on and sometimes the behavior is totally unpredictable.

I made a test load consisting of a \$220 \ \Omega\$ resistor in series with a diode.  I turn on the relay and Q12. When I connect the load across pin 1 and 4 of J21 and J22 respectively it pulls a constant 14.769mA, as it should. If I instead connect the load across pin 4 and pin 1 of J21 and J22 respectively the current is 7 mA and it keeps decreasing until it reaches 0 mA.

Pictures of test setup: -

[image]

My first thought was that Q12 was damaged from ESD, and so I have changed it two times but the unwanted behavior persists. I have also tried replacing all the surface mount components but nothing changed.

I haven't changed the relay or pin headers, but I have no reason to believe they could cause any problems. What could be wrong with my circuit or components?

Note that there are 4 identical circuits on the same board. The 1st and 4th circuit have this unwanted behavior with Q12, and it seems after further investigations that the 2nd also suffer but the 3rd is fine. I suspect that it is because the source of Q12 is not at the same potential as the Arduino's GND but that doesn't explain how circuit 3 acts as it it supposed to.

My PCB layout can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3oh1.png).

### Entire circuit board

[image]

Using the same power supply terminal as both \$V_\text{SUPPLY}\$ and as input voltage removes the problem - probably because the source of the MOSFET is now GND and not floating: -

[image]

Comment: What is the voltage at Q12s gate when on / off?

Comment: @MiNiMe It is 0 V with respect to the Arduino's GND. By the way, I just noticed that connecting the ground clip of my oscilloscope probe to the GND header (31) affects the circuit behavior. Also, unplugging my computer (which the Arduino is powered by) from the wall did something.

Comment: Check that your grounds are truly connected. || If scope does not have groundedearth wire then scope ground can have highZ Vmains/2 on it. || What is Arduino supply voltage? 5V = Vsupply or other? (THat's inferred but MAY be ambigiuous.)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The Arduino is supplied via my computer through a micro-USB.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I know comments aren’t suited for discussions, but would replacing the NMOS transistor with a BJT mitigate the problem with the floating source? I have no experience with BJT’s other than they are current controlled.

Comment: The output of that bench PSU is probably floating w.r.t. mains earth unless you connect, say, the 0 V terminal to the ground terminal. "Probably" is because I can't make out the model number to check.

Comment: @Carl No. Grounds must all be connected. FET is easier to use than BJT in this circuit as long as drive is adequate. If Vdrive is 3V3 this FET is very marginal. BUT what you see appears to be a ground linkage issue.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Is there no apparent way to avoid this problem without having to redesign the entire circuit?

Comment: @Carl  Are all grouds connected? If so it's not the issue. || If NOT then (1) Why NOT. (2) Can they be connected without problem? || Please indicatee situatuon. || A solution will beeasy once we proerly understand the problem :-).  Redesign unlikely to be needed.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon All grounds are connected. My PCB uses two GND planes and many stitching vias, so they are at same potentials. So the on board Arduino and the power supply supplying the board have the same GND. The source of Q12 is not GND, but is \$V_{\text{diff},-}\$ of a differential input signal. The source supplying this differential signal has its own internal grounding system, and must not have its \$V_{\text{diff},-}\$ as board GND.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sorry for bothering you so much, but I really need the help. Is there an alternative 3-legged component component I can use instead of an NMOS as switch? I really need this switch to be reliable and deterministic (i.e. it doesn't become unpredictable).

Comment: @Carl Any amount of questions are OK BUT you also need to carefully examine what people tell you (others as well as me). So far it sounds as though what I & others say is the problem. || I'd expect  the circuit to work when  J20-2 is grounded. Q12 then has correct Vgs drive. BUT when J20-2 is at some arbitrary voltage aove ground Q12-Vgs will be reduced accordingly and if VJ20-2 is high enough above ground Q12 will not have enough drive.  An optocouple will do what you want. D3 (which you do not mention but allude to) to ground turns the opto on. Opto out is above present Q12_d-s. ...

Comment: ... You can do this with two transistors (which can be kluged onto the current board  BUT you need to tell us more. || What is the range of the voltages on J20-1 and J20-2? || Is J20-1 always above J20-2 or ...? || Can they both be negative, above Vcc, below ground ...? || What minimum load R is used? Why a diode? || A diagram of allowable voltages on both pins may be needed, or a word description may do. |||The solution varies deep-ending on these answers. || A second relay does what you want BUT is probably not what you want.

Comment: You are essentially wanting "The sound of one hand clapping". ie the control signal MUST be relative to a reference point which becomes a "terminal" of your device. In a non-isolated control circuit the extra terminal is achieved by commoning the control "ground" with one of the signal leads. That provides "the other hand".  Just waving the control lead (or hand) in the air without a reference relative to some point defined in the circuit does not work. Having the reference as eg Arduino_ground somewhere offstae BUT not connecting it to anything in the circuit does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have common GND between the circuit you're driving and the Arduino + relay circuit. As the gate voltage is relative to the source, Q12 floats (if that term can be used here). If you need to keep the two GND separated use an optocoupler or another relay.

Comment: Though I agree, I was hoping for another answer than this because this doesn't explain everything. Circuit 3 on my board is works exactly as it should even though that circuit's MOSFET's source is also floating.

Comment: So there's more? Could you be kind and add that circuit as well?

Comment: Without seeing that part of the schematic, it is impossible to say.  However, an floating 2N7000 gate is a very small capacitor with a parallel resistance of G ohms.  At that impedance, fingerprint oil on the PC board can affect behavior.

Comment: @MiNiMe It's the same circuit copy pasted 4 times (as seen in the pictures of my setup), so the topology is identical. Therefore, there should be no difference between the two's operation.

Comment: Do all the controlled circuits have common ground?

Comment: Regarding *there should* be no diff, in a perfect world no. But here you're in no mans land, where the FETs can behave very random. Small deviations between the circuits make a big difference in the end.

Comment: @MiNiMe The gate voltage of all MOSFETs are controlled by a digital output of the Arduino. Thus, all controlled circuits have common GND.

Comment: Thanks. I hope you got it solved, and in a not too costly manner.